# how to increment final attribute variable in constructor?

Tags: java, increment, final

In my homework, I have a Java class with attributes

```
private final int idOfPassenger;
private final String name;
```

in the constructor which takes only a `String` as parameter, I am supposed to initialise both the name and the id of the passenger. But every time I create a `new Passenger`, I am supposed to increment the `idOfPassenger` variable by one (starting from 0), so no passengers have the same number.

I am not allowed to change the `private final` or the constructor parameters.
How do I increment `idOfPassengers` by 1 every time I create a new passenger?

```
public class Passenger {

    private final int idOfPassenger;
    private final String name;

    public Passenger(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.idOfPassenger = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely intended to have another variable that keeps track of the next ID to use, which then would not be final and would be static. `private static int nextPassengerId = 0;`. You would then do `idOfPassenger = nextPassengerId;` and increment that by one, `nextPassengerId++;`. Be aware of multithreading issues, use `AtomicInteger` instead for `nextPassengerId`, if that is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of a final field is that it cannot be reassigned to a new value. So you cannot increment it. But you misunderstand the assignment. You are not supposed to increment `private final int idOfPassenger;` of your existing objects but instead always initialize it with one value higher than the last created object when creating a new object. You can realize that behavior by introducing a static field that belongs to the class and not any specific object:

```
public class Passenger {

    private final int idOfPassenger;
    private final String name;
    private static int currentId = 0;

    public Passenger(String name) {
        currentId++;
        this.name = name;
        this.idOfPassenger = currentId;
    }
}
```

This will create a static field that belong to the class and all your objects share. It is initialized with 0, then each time a new object gets created that static field is incremented and the `final int idOfPassenger` value set to the current value of that static field.

Comment: Thank you! In the code you wrote, would the first passenger then have ID 0 or ID 1?

Comment: 1: The incrementing of `currentId` happens before assigning it to `idOfPassenger`.